# in a php loop, how to continue to the next iteration if the current one craches

Tags: php

i have a loop like that

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $row->executeThatFunction();
}
.
.
.
public function executeThatFunction($someVariable) {
    // do something that may craches
}
```

So i want to continue looping even if the executeThatFunction() craches (php error for example)

How can i do that ?
PS : i'm working on symfony2 project, so if symfony provide some solution for that case i'll be glad to learn it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

Can i do something like that ?

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
try {
    $row->executeThatFunction();
} catch($e)
{
continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Some php errors are recoverable and some are not.

Comment: Work with exceptions? http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: About your edit: The general  `try` / `catch` idea is good but using `continue` in a loop that only contains 1 statement is pointless.

Comment: Errors that i want to override is something like "undefined variable" or "undefined index" etc. Is catch (Exception $e) is capable to hundle that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your using php7: php7 throws errors like exceptions. And all recoverable errors are catchable. And also both errors and exceptions implement a common interface called `Throwable`.

That means you can surround your call with a try-catch-block and simply continue the loop, when a throwable error occurs:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    try {
        $row->executeThatFunction();
    } catch (Throwable $t) {
        // you may want to add some logging here...
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually haven't encountered Throwable, very useful, every day is a school day!

Comment: No. In php5 you cannot catch errors, only exceptions. `catch (Exception $e)`. But that might be enough in your case. If not, i'd first try to make sure, that your function does not run into any errors...

Comment: Errors that i want to override is something like "undefined variable" or "undefined index" etc. Is catch (Exception $e) is capable to hundle that ?

Comment: No, that are no Exceptions. I guess you mean simple php Notices like `Notice: Undefined index...`. But these wont really **crash** your function. Only in dev environment, because symfony will wrap these Notices in exceptions and finally respond with http 500 and an error page. Can't you simply get rid of these Notices by fixing them? Or maybe you just want to suppress them by using [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) : `@$row->executeThatFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use try ... catch block in your function:

```
public function executeThatFunction($someVariable) {
    try {
// do something that may craches
    } catch($e)
   {
 // handle your error here          
   }
}
```

Comment: can i do somethin like that ?
foreach ($array as $row) {
try {
    $row->executeThatFunction();
} catch($e)
{
continue;
   }
}

Comment: Ofcourse! You can handle exceptions everywhere in your code

Comment: Errors that i want to override is something like "undefined variable" or "undefined index" etc. Is catch (Exception $e) is capable to hundle that ?